# How would you search for this type of screen?

Tags: lcd, 7segmentdisplay

I have this cooking thermometer with a very small screen. For my DIY projects I'd like to buy some of these screens in bulk (say 10 or 20) and use them with arduino but I can't find a proper name to search them with. It seems to be something between a 7-segments display and an LCD screen, probably designed specifically for this application. How would you go about searching something similar on the marketplace?

[image: thermometer]

EDIT: I'm adding that I'm specifically interested in these very small screens. The one in the picture is 10mm X 25mm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Raw LCD glass is a thing

What you're looking at is a slightly customized seven-segment LCD "raw glass" display that requires the user to provide the appropriate AC drive waveforms.  While the *specific* display you're seeing there is custom and therefore not available, you can get generic seven-segment, multi-digit LCD glass through the usual suspects.  You'll need a LCD driver chip to drive whatever glass you get though, as for 3-4 digits it'll likely be too multiplexed to "bit bang" the AC drive waveforms (Silicon Labs makes the CP240x family that can be talked to via I2C or SPI).

Comment: This is very interesting. I did not know about raw glass or about how difficult it is to drive barebone. thank you

Answer (score 1):

That is an LCD display. There are various types but the small ones (2-3 digits) are more difficult to control as they need an AC signal on the pins. The bigger modules have a controller which takes care of that. Digi-key, Mouser, Farnell, RS, Future electronics should have some.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try searching on the sites you named.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "alphanumeric LCD Module". Those are the easiest to control.

Comment: If I search for that all I come up with are the classical 16x2 arduino modules while I'm specifically interested in these small sized ones. I'll add this information to the original post

Comment: You can try "[number of characters you want]x1 LCD Module"

Comment: where are you searching (please, please, please tell me it's not ebay or aliexpress...)

Comment: @MarcusMüller it actually is the two above plus banggood as I'd like to spend 1$ or less/screen. I'm welcome to suggestions though.

Comment: so, aus user353... said in the [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/345439/64158), any reputable electronics distributor. Seriously, unless you're building a couple of thousand devices, what do you gain by saving a dollar or two on aliexpress? Instead of something that comes with a good drawing, and datasheets on the manufacturer's website, you get something that might or might not work as expected, comes weeks after you need it, doesn't have sufficient documentation but the pictures on the product website that someone obviously copied from somewhere else...

Comment: The bucks you save per screen is what you pay in your own time and frustration. Now, if you're **actually planning** to build a couple thousand devices, still: reputable distributors, you don't want 5% of these to fail, and also, at sufficient numbers, these things get cheaper & you can directly talk to the manufacturer. Believe me, for electronic components, china direct import *just doesn't pay*.